# Bring HABTM data to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to make a table for the User of the site to see what groups each person is in. I have a Groups table and a People table. Right now I want just the groups of a single person to show up in the view. I will show you my code for clarification. This is my table.

`<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= sortable 'phone_number', 'Phone Number'%></th>
        <th><%= sortable 'subscribed', 'Subscribed State'%></th>
        <th><%= sortable 'groups' %></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @groups.each do |group| %>
        <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= person.phone_number %></td>
          <td><%= person.subscribed %></td>
          <td><%= group.name %></td>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>`

Right now every group is showing up for each person whether or not they belong to each group. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd need to see your Group and People models to be sure, but most likely what you need to do is loop over `person.groups`. Something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= person.phone_number %></td>
      <td><%= person.subscribed %></td>

      <% person.groups.each do |group| %>
          <td><%= group.name %></td>
      <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

That way you would be just iterating over the `groups` belonging to the individual `person`, rather than all the `groups` in your database.

Note that if you format it this way, unless every person is in the same number of groups, your table rows will be of differing lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
group.people.each do |person|
```

instead of

```
@people.each do |person|
```

to iterate through all users in each group.